# Prevent input inside a bootstrap modal losing focus when click on modal's scrollbar

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I have an input inside a modal. If the input has focus and i click on the modal's scrollbar the input loses focus. How can i prevent this to occur?

Browsers default behavior is to not remove inputs focus when you click on a scrollbar, however inside a bootstrap modal this is not happening.

Example:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>



<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModalNorm">
    Launch Form
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModalNorm" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" 
     aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <!-- Modal Header -->
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" 
                   data-dismiss="modal">
                       <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                       <span class="sr-only">Close</span>
                </button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">
                    Modal title
                </h4>
            </div>
            
            <!-- Modal Body -->
            <div class="modal-body">
                
                <form role="form">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
                      <input type="email" class="form-control"
                      id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Enter email"/>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
                      <input type="password" class="form-control"
                          id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password"/>
                  </div>
                  
                </form>
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
            </div>
            
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it's browser behavior caused by the modal's container having the tabindex="-1" attribute.

I suppose an ugly workaround would be to listen for the blur event. If the modal is still open and nothing within the modal has focus, return the focus

Answer (score 1):

Not the perfect answer

```js
var inputs = document.getElementById('myModalNorm').getElementsByTagName('input');

var focused;

for(let i=0; i<inputs.length; i++){
inputs[i].addEventListener('focus', function(){
  focused = document.activeElement;
});
}

document.getElementById('myModalNorm').addEventListener('scroll', function(){
  if(focused){
    focused.focus();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>



<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModalNorm">
    Launch Form
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModalNorm" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" 
     aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <!-- Modal Header -->
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" 
                   data-dismiss="modal">
                       <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                       <span class="sr-only">Close</span>
                </button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">
                    Modal title
                </h4>
            </div>
            
            <!-- Modal Body -->
            <div class="modal-body">
                
                <form role="form">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
                      <input type="email" class="form-control"
                      id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Enter email"/>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
                      <input type="password" class="form-control"
                          id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password"/>
                  </div>
                  
                </form>
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
            </div>
            
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I dealt with the errant tabindex attribute:

```
let create_modal = $('#create-modal');
create_draft_asset_modal.on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
    create_modal.removeAttr('tabindex');
}).on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
    create_modal.attr('tabindex', '-1');
});
```